# OLEDB date(time) issue asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I have written a little excel helper which works fine. It uses this connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<FILENAME>;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
```

Unfortunately when I deploy the code, cells, which contains a date string like this: `28/12/2008` are returned as: `12/25/2008 12:00:00 AM` rather than `25/12/2008 00:00:00` **after using ToString**. I adjusted the time zone etc. of the machine (all machines are now UK time zones) but this hasn't changed anything. I am just curious what determines how OLEDB 'behaves'. The aim would be to get `25/12/2008 00:00:00` on both machines.

Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 2):

I think that this might be something to do with the `Culture` being set to `en-us`.  You would need to format the `DateTime` accordingly.

[Standard Date and Time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: The ToString function gives me either 12/25/2008 12:00:00 AM or 25/12/2008 00:00:00 depending on the machine. I would like to synch the machines

Comment: Use `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` to keep it in the same format no matter what machine it is installed on.

Comment: No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments

Comment: What is the `type` of your variable?

Comment: It is a datatable and when I do gettype i get datetime but despite this i cannot use ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").

Comment: I have now noticed that one column is of type system.string and the other of type system.datetime despite the fact that i formated them as date in excel. so i am not sure what's going on there. i have managed to write some working code ... i check whether it is system.datetime and then just type cast. otherwise i transform things manually. still a pain though. do not understand why this oledb stuff does not work as it should do.

Answer (score 1):

The machines may need to have their locale settings changed, and not just the timezone settings. I believe they are separate.

Comment: I have changed the reginal and language options to UK. Do you know where to change what you refer to?

Comment: If you changed the regional I think that covers it. You may be stuck formatting your dates manually? http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Format_Specifiers%E2%80%94DateTime_Format_Specifiers

Answer (score 1):

You have American datetime settings, either change this or use the numberformat to show it in the format you want, see http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/datetime.htm